# Objective-C implementation of a histogram or bag datastructure

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, histogram, multimap, bag

Instead of implementing my own I was wondering if anyone knows of a histogram or bag datastructure implementation in Objective-C that I can use.

Essentially a histogram is a hashmap of lists where the lists contain values that relate to their hash entry. A good example is a histogram of supermarket items where you place each group of items dairy, meat, canned goods in their own bag. You can then very easily access each group of items according to their type.

Comment: Would an NSDictionary of NSArrays (or NSSets) not be sufficient?

Comment: Do you need something more than just an NSDictionary containing NSArray's (or NSSet's, if dupes are not allowed)?

Comment: @Chuck - our comments are eerily similar!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (aka "bag") that counts distinct objects, but doesn't allow duplicates. However, based on your explanation, I don't think that's what you need, and neither is a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), which automatically buckets values based on a set of (usually numerical) ranges.

I believe what you really want is a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), which is a "key to one-or-more values" relation. The [data structures framework](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures) I maintain includes [CHMultiDictionary](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/interface_c_h_multi_dictionary.html), a multimap implementation. I won't claim by any means that it's perfect or complete, but I hope it may be helpful for your problem.

Comment: Note: My CHMultiDictionary stores the values for each key in a set, so no duplicates are permitted. If you want to allow duplicate values, you'll probably want something more like what Peter suggests. Perhaps modifying my code so the user can decide whether to allow duplicates would be a nice touch...

Comment: Another possibility is the OHHashMultiMap class in ObjectiveLib. (http://objectivelib.sourceforge.net/NoOpenStep/interfaceOLHashMultiMap.html) The downside is that this library is much closer to STL than to the Cocoa collections — the APIs don't quite match up and the concepts are quite different from NS(Mutable)Dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you simply want a dictionary of arrays.  You can put NSArrays as elements of NSDictionarys, something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"milk", @"eggs", @"cheese", nil] forKey:@"dairy"];
[dict setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"steak", @"sausages", @"mince", nil] forKey:@"meat"];

[[dict objectForKey:@"meat"] addObject:@"lamb"];

NSLog( @"Dictionary is %@", dict );
```

Answer (score 1):

There's one in the [GNU Objective-C Class library](http://directory.fsf.org/project/libobjects/), but the [docs](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/libobjects/libobjects_39.html) appear to be pretty incomplete and the project's [homepage](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/mccallum/libobjects/) must be currently having a problem -- still, if GPL software is acceptable for your project, you might want to [download](ftp://ftp.cs.rochester.edu/pub/u/mccallum/libobjects/gstep-base-0.2.11.tar.gz) and check the sources.

Comment: From what I can tell, that library project seems pretty dead. It says it has become part of GNUstep, but I couldn't find anything promising in the GNUstep SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

[CFIOMultimap](https://gist.github.com/CodaFi/6801932) apparently is an implementation of a multimap. However, as of the time of writing I couldn't get it to work. It returns nils all the time when I subscript.

Perhaps it can be fixed and adapted for your use.