# Multiple values per key in dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating an application which retrieves a list of adresses for a specific coutnry and groups them in a dictionary by the first letter. So Amsterdam will be placed under the key "A".

These adresses are read from a CSV file and iterated over. The problem I'm having is that I made a dictionary with the keys A-Z.

In my for loop I would like to add every address to the correct key, but since it's in a loop I only have ony address at a time. [dictionary setObject] will only place in the last value.

How should I approach this?

Comment: It would help if you gave a breakdown of what you would like the structure to be.   Do you want a dictionary with the keys A to Z containing a dictionary of countries which in turn contain an array (or set) of cities?

Comment: No basically what I want is a Dictonary with keys from A-Z with only Country names added to the right key. So:

N - Netherlands, Norway, Nepal
U - United States of America

Comment: What does this question have to do with the Xcode IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `NSDictionary` (A-Z) of `NSMutableArrays`? You will then be able to add items like this:

```
for (NSString* theName in (...)) {
    NSString* firstLetter = [[theName substringToIndex:1] uppercase];

    // Check this in case there is 'malformed' input, e.g. strings beginning
    // with non-alpha characters
    if ([theDictionary objectForKey:firstLetter]) {
        [theDictionary[firstLetter] addObject:theName];
    } else {
            NSLog(@"Skipping item %@", theName);
    }
}
```

You can initialize `theDictionary` like this:

```
theDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    theDictionary[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c]] = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

Comment: I think this should work great.. I'm going to give that a try tonight. Will accept your answer! thanks

Comment: what's the best way to initialize the dictionary with NSMUteableArrays? I'm new at objective-c and I've seen a few options at stackoverflow

Comment: You're awesome. This clarifies a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A `NSDictionary` that holds multiple values for a single key is what most people call a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap).

So I hunted around for some multimap implementations and found [CFIOMultimap](https://gist.github.com/CodaFi/6801932), which on the surface of it looks like a well-written class. I like using a specific data type because because it describes the data structure much better.

However, it doesn't seem to work for me and every time I try to subscript it I get nils. You can try it for yourself and let us know whether it's of any use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997606/objective-c-implementation-of-a-histogram-or-bag-datastructure is also somewhat related.